# Google logo does not show up in Google Map (IPad Application)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-maps

I have a IPad application in which I add MKMapView programmatically without using the NIB.

```
{
CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 980);

//CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1004, 1004);

mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:r];
mapView.showsUserLocation = FALSE;
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
//mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
//mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
mapView.delegate = self;

/*Region and Zoom*/
// one degree = 69 miles

// get the distance
// .01 = 1 mile square
//float distance = controller.itemDistance;

float distance = 1.0;
distance = distance/100.0;

MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta = distance;
span.longitudeDelta = distance;

CLLocationCoordinate2D location = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
location.latitude = currLocation.coordinate.latitude;
location.longitude = currLocation.coordinate.longitude;

region.span = span;
region.center = location;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
[self addSubview:mapView];

[self addAnnotation];
```

}

The problem that I am facing is that the GOOGLE Logo Does not show up at the bottom of the MAP and also not showing the copyright notice. Due to this the application has been rejected from App Store. Can anyone help to add the logo on the MAP ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe the frame of you MKMapView is larger than the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be your mapview is bigger than your view that you want to add in. Log frame height and width of view, and see if it is smaller than mapView. 
Also consider to add `[self setClipToBounds:NO];` and see mapView is flooding.